# How to show a custom dialog with FAB click?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I tried creating a custom dialog with a layout.  I haven't added any functionality to the dialog yet.  At the moment, I'm trying to launch it with a FAB click from the MainActivity.

This is my custom dialog:

```
public class GenerateDialog extends Fragment implements DialogInterface.OnCancelListener, DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, container, false);
    }

    ...
}
```

And this is my `MainActivity`.  I don't know how I'm suppose to launch the dialog in the `onClick`.  I tried using an intent but it threw an error for casting the dialog as an activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    GenerateDialog generateDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        generateDialog = new GenerateDialog();

        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Show GenerateDialog

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason to extends from `Fragment` and nor `Dialog/DialogFragment...` for your `GenerateDialog ` class

Comment: `DialogFragment` is deprecated

Comment: So just `Dialog`, any reason for your class not to extend `Dialog`?

Comment: No reason.  This is what was suggested by the docs when I was reading about `DialogFragment`.

Comment: Also, check my answer you can use single dialog and display it according to the calledBy and with your custom message

Comment: @AbhishekBhardwaj I've already accepted an answer but I've given you an upvote out of appreciation.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Comment: Appreciate your upvote and I  Already upvote you  @oo92 I was saying I provide you full custom solution one dialog for your whole app you should try that one also.

Comment: I'll definitely give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done something similar, your dialog class should extend Dialog and not Fragment.
It should be: `public class GenerateDialog extends Dialog`

And then on the constructor you inflate it:

```
public class GenerateDialog extends Dialog {

public GenerateDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    }
 … 
}
```

On your FAB listener, after you have initiated your object, you can just invoke show() (f.i. if your object is named generateDialog, you execute `generateDialog.show();` after you instantiate it, as it is required for a dialog to appear).

F.i.:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    GenerateDialog generateDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        generateDialog = new GenerateDialog(this);

        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                generateDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can show your dialog like this

```
public class CustomDialog extends Activity {

    private static Context context;

    private static Dialog dialog;
    public static void dialog(final Context ctxt, final String calledBy,
                              String title, String message, String buttonText) {

        context = ctxt;

        if( dialog != null && dialog.isShowing() ) return;

        dialog = new Dialog(context);

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transparent);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_single_button);

        TextView txtTitle = dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        TextView txtMessage = dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        TextView tvOK = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvOK);

        txtTitle.setText(title);
        txtMessage.setText(message);
        tvOK.setText(buttonText);



        dialog.show();

    }
```

And call it like this

```
CustomDialogSingleButton.dialog(context,
                        Constants.SYNC_FILES
                        , context.getResources().getString(R.string.sync_files_title),
                        context.getResources().getString(R.string.sync_files_msg), "OK");
```

Just try this code and your dialog will appear

Answer (score 1):

Code for dialog fragment

```
public class MyCustomDialog extends DialogFragment{

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(android.app.DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, container, false);
return v;
}

}
```

and call this MyCustomDialog from your activity like below,

```
 MyCustomDialog dialog = new MyCustomDialog();
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 dialog.show(ft, MyCustomDialog.TAG);
```

Comment: I've already accepted someone's answer but thank you for your effort.  I've given you an upvote.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you upvote me as well?

Comment: Keep in mind that DialogFragment has been deprecated in API 28 and  you need to use the support version.

Answer (score 0):

> **Custom View**

```
<!-- fragment_edit_name.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/edit_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical"  >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_your_name" android:text="Your name" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_your_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:inputType="text"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and defining the fragment itself extending from the support version of dialog fragment:

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
// ...

public class EditNameDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private EditText mEditText;

    public EditNameDialogFragment() {
        // Empty constructor is required for DialogFragment
                // Make sure not to add arguments to the constructor
                // Use `newInstance` instead as shown below
    }

    public static EditNameDialogFragment newInstance(String title) {
        EditNameDialogFragment frag = new EditNameDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_name, container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // Get field from view
        mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_your_name);
        // Fetch arguments from bundle and set title
        String title = getArguments().getString("title", "Enter Name");
        getDialog().setTitle(title);
        // Show soft keyboard automatically and request focus to field
        mEditText.requestFocus();
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

and showing the dialog in an Activity extending AppCompatActivity:

call **`showEditDialog()`** method from onclick method of **FAB**

```
private void showEditDialog() {
      FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
      EditNameDialogFragment editNameDialogFragment = EditNameDialogFragment.newInstance("Some Title");
      editNameDialogFragment.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
  }
```

check for [info](https://guides.codepath.com/android)